# WordPress Login Footer URL

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I want to change the url of the Wordpress 'Back to XXXX' on the wordpress url.

I've used this function to change the logo url, but there doesnt seem to be a footerurl reference.

```
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_login_header_url' );
function custom_login_header_url($url) {
  return 'http://www.myurl.com/';
}
```

Any ideas how I can change this url with a filter? My wordpress installation is a micro-site sitting under a main site, which is why I want it to go to a different url that `home_url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not a standard feature you could achieve this 
with your own css and js you could add to the page like this

```
    <?php
    function custom_login() { 
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/custom-login/custom-login.css" />'; 
    echo '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>'
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo("template_url") . '/js/yourScript.js"></script>';
    }
    add_action('login_head', 'custom_login');
    ?>
```

change jquery url as wanted to get last version.

The div id where the link is in is called `#backtoblog`

you could change the innerhtml using javascript/jquery.

```
$('#backtoblog').html('<a href="http://gotomyblog.com">go back</a>');
```

or you could use css to get rid of it.

```
#backtoblog{display:none;}
```

like this.

enjoy

Comment: Hi, this sent me down the right path but there are a few problems with your answer. a) JS call is a CSS link b) No jQuery loaded (I load this aswell).

Comment: yeah, my bad , copy paste nastyness. let me fix it.

Comment: Ok, I can accept it then. Cheers.

Comment: should be better now, my bad for being messy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding so many files, which you don't need. Use plain ol' JavaScript for this.

```
/**
 * Change Back to URL on login.
 *
 * Change Back to Home URL on login page.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wpse61784_change_back_to_url() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var backToBlog = document.getElementById( 'backtoblog' ).getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[0];
        backToBlog.setAttribute( 'href', 'https://NEW-URL.com/' );
        backToBlog.innerHTML='&larr; Back to NEW TEXT';
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Hook it.
add_action( 'login_footer', 'wpse61784_change_back_to_url' );
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've amended the above answer by @woony to include jQuery and outputted my function differently.

```
function custom_login() { 
    ?>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/custom-login.js"></script
<?php }
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login');
```

The custom-login.js

```
  $(function(){
        $('#backtoblog').html('<a href="http://xxx">&larr; Go back</a>');
  });
```